# SQL Server jdbc driver not connect remote server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server whose database installation was done using an instance. When I try to connect to the server using the microsoft driver (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver), it returns an error stating that it could not connect. Using the same driver but connecting to a local database, it connects successfully.

The error is not in the SQL Server TCP/IP configuration, because if I make the connection using the "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" driver, the application connects to the database.

But I can't use the jtds driver, because I'm using JetBrains / Exposed and it requires the use of the microsoft driver. So I need to make it work with "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

URL when I try to connect on SQL Server

```
jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER1:1433;database=db_test;instanceName=SQL2016;loginTimeout=5;
```

Error message

```
org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falha na conexão TCP/IP com o host ITALIA, porta 1433. Erro: "connect timed out. Verifique as propriedades da conexão. Verifique se uma instância do SQL Server está sendo executada no host e se está aceitando conexões TCP/IP na porta. Verifique se as conexões TCP na porta não foram bloqueadas por um firewall.".
SQL: [SELECT 1 AS Test]
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.Statement.executeIn$exposed(Statement.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:128)
```

URL when I connect a local server successfully

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=db_test;loginTimeout=20;
```

URL when I connect successfully using jtds driver

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER1:1433/db_test;instance=SQL2016;loginTimeout=30
```

Comment: If you want to connect by instance name, remove the port number (and make sure the SQL Server Browser service is running), or make sure you specify the correct port number that matches the instance name (see the note at `portNumber` at [Setting the connection properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver16)). And please include the full exception stacktrace in your question.

Comment: In the first connection string, you have the host as `//localhost:1433` and the database as `db_test`, in the latter you are trying to connect to `//SERVER1:1433/db_test;` Why aren't using `//SERVER1:1433;database=db_test`? YOu also define the instance name as `SQL2016` in the second connection string, but you don't define one in the first.

Comment: Thanks Mark Rotteveel, now works.